# How can I create a new unrelated file when using a drag-and-drop file as an argument?

Tags: file, vbscript

My goal is to have a VBS file that I can drag-and-drop a text file onto which will then filter out lines in that text file containing a substring, then write the remaining lines to a new file. (Incomplete) code follows:

```
Dim fso, oFile, iFile
Dim Arg
Dim curLine, foundMatch, FilteredLines()
Const READ = 1, WRITE = 2, APPEND = 8
ReDim Preserve FilteredLines(0)
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
        Arg = Trim(Wscript.Arguments(0))
        Set iFile=fso.OpenTextFile(Arg, READ, true)
        Do Until iFile.AtEndOfStream
                curLine = iFile.ReadLine
                foundMatch = InStr(curLine, "Threshold")
                IF foundMatch = 0 Then
                        ReDim Preserve FilteredLines (UBound(FilteredLines) + 1)
                        FilteredLines(UBound(FilteredLines)) = curLine
                        'msgBox curLine
                End If
        Loop
        iFile.Close
End If 

Set oFile=fso.OpenTextFile("next.txt", WRITE, true) 'This is line 23

For Each Arg in FilteredLines
        oFile.WriteLine(Arg)
Next
oFile.Close
```

The problem is: If I just double-click the file, the 'next.txt' file is created with no issue. If I drag-and-drop a file over this script, everything in the 'If' statement seems to fire correctly, but then I get the following error:

```
Script: {path to script}
Line: 23 (notated in code)
Char: 1
Error: Permission Denied
Code: 800A0046
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

So it seems that I can either have the drag and drop parse work or generate the output file, but not both. How can I resolve this issue? (This is the first time I've ever worked with VBScript.)

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved:
Apparently naming the output file "next.txt" without a directory and within the context of taking in a drag-and-dropped file as input was causing it to try and write to some directory that I didn't have access to.

I used the fso object to get the current directory and qualified "next.txt" with that directory and everything's working fine.